# How to clear specific image from cache in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, caching

How can I remove specific image-url from cache? I've read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209606/how-do-i-clear-flutters-image-cache) question, but the accepted answer is clearing all the cache, also I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465356/flutter-cache-manager-clear-cache-for-specific-urls) one that is using a library (that I don't want to use). Does flutter have any ability to clear specific image that is already cached by:

```
precacheImage(NetworkImage(imageAddress), context);
```

The reason is that I have a page full of cached-images, I want to clear them all (to free memory) when the user passes it and goes to another page (after all, do I need do this?).